# Nested ngFor Ionic 2 : Not working

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

```
"fields": [
                {
                    "type": "radio",
                    "id": 1,
                    "label": "1. I want to view the Sleep Presentation because I want to get some insight into my own sleep issues.",
                    "adminLabel": "",
                    "isRequired": true,
                    "size": "medium",
                    "errorMessage": "",
                    "inputs": null,
                    "choices": [
                        {
                            "text": "No, Not Really",
                            "value": "No, Not Really",
                            "isSelected": false,
                            "price": ""
                        },
                        {
                            "text": "Somewhat",
                            "value": "Somewhat",
                            "isSelected": false,
                            "price": ""
                        },
                        {
                            "text": "Yes, Definitely",
                            "value": "Yes, Definitely",
                            "isSelected": false,
                            "price": ""
                        }
                    ],
                    "formId": 30,
                    "description": "(If you answer here is (b) or (c), in addition to viewing the presentation, also complete the  Sleep Questionnaire to get your report.)",
                    "allowsPrepopulate": false,
                    "inputMask": false,
                    "inputMaskValue": "",
                    "inputType": "",
                    "labelPlacement": "",
                    "descriptionPlacement": "above",
                    "subLabelPlacement": "",
                    "placeholder": "",
                    "cssClass": "",
                    "inputName": "",
                    "visibility": "visible",
                    "noDuplicates": false,
                    "defaultValue": "",
                    "conditionalLogic": "",
                    "productField": "",
                    "enableOtherChoice": "",
                    "enablePrice": "",
                    "multipleFiles": false,
                    "maxFiles": "",
                    "calculationFormula": "",
                    "calculationRounding": "",
                    "enableCalculation": "",
                    "disableQuantity": false,
                    "displayAllCategories": false,
                    "useRichTextEditor": false,
                    "enableChoiceValue": false,
                    "pageNumber": 1,
                    "displayOnly": ""
                },
                {
                    "type": "radio",
                    "id": 2,
                    "label": "2. I want to view the Sleep Presentation because I want to get some insight into Sleep issues because someone I know has sleep problems",
                    "adminLabel": "",
                    "isRequired": true,
                    "size": "medium",
                    "errorMessage": "",
                    "inputs": null,
                    "choices": [
                        {
                            "text": "No, That Isn't Why I'm Interested",
                            "value": "No, That Isn't Why I'm Interested",
                            "isSelected": false,
                            "price": ""
                        },
                        {
                            "text": "Partly, There Is Someone Close To Me With Sleep Issues",
                            "value": "Partly, There Is Someone Close To Me With Sleep Issues",
                            "isSelected": false,
                            "price": ""
                        },
                        {
                            "text": "Yes, That Is The Main Reason For My Interest",
                            "value": "Yes, That Is The Main Reason For My Interest",
                            "isSelected": false,
                            "price": ""
                        }
                    ],
                    "formId": 30,
                    "description": "",
                    "allowsPrepopulate": false,
                    "inputMask": false,
                    "inputMaskValue": "",
                    "inputType": "",
                    "labelPlacement": "",
                    "descriptionPlacement": "",
                    "subLabelPlacement": "",
                    "placeholder": "",
                    "cssClass": "",
                    "inputName": "",
                    "visibility": "visible",
                    "noDuplicates": false,
                    "defaultValue": "",
                    "conditionalLogic": "",
                    "productField": "",
                    "enableOtherChoice": "",
                    "enablePrice": "",
                    "multipleFiles": false,
                    "maxFiles": "",
                    "calculationFormula": "",
                    "calculationRounding": "",
                    "enableCalculation": "",
                    "disableQuantity": false,
                    "displayAllCategories": false,
                    "useRichTextEditor": false,
                    "pageNumber": 1,
                    "displayOnly": ""
                },
```

Which is a form data that needs to be rendered in a view. However when I perform a nested ngFor in the view, I can't get the data inside the choices, the page always shows blank data.

```
 <div class="form-group">
          <ion-list *ngFor="let field of form.fields">
            <!-- TYPE == RADIO -->
            <ion-item *ngIf="field.type == 'radio'">
                <ion-list radio-group>
                    <ion-list-header>
                        <p style="white-space: normal;">{{ field.label }}</p>
                    </ion-list-header>
                    <ion-item *ngFor="let choice of field.choices">
                        <ion-label>{{ choice.text }}</ion-label>
                        <ion-radio value="{{ choice.value }}"></ion-radio>
                    </ion-item>
                </ion-list>
            </ion-item>
          </ion-list>
</div>
```

This is how I get the data from the api:

```
this.apiService.postForm(this.form.id).subscribe(
            data => {
                this.form_structure = data.data.structure;
            },
            error => console.log(error)
        );
```

Then I pass it into a modal page like this:

```
var data = { 'form' : this.form_structure };
var modalPage = this.modalCtrl.create(ModalPage,data);
modalPage.present();
```

I've been reading solutions and many say that `let choice of field.choices` this should work but I've tried multiple times nothing is working for me. Any idea ?

Comment: Can you show how `form` or `fields` is declared?

Comment: @AugustinR I've updated my question above

Comment: Nested for loop works: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6ge7jw?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: @SujataChanda it is working for a text input but not working for a radio input

Comment: Working for radio also: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dhyogr?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've updated my work and this is now working.

```
<ion-list *ngIf="field.type == 'list'" radio-group>
                        <ion-list-header>
                            <p style="white-space: normal;">{{ field.label }}</p>
                        </ion-list-header>
                        <ion-item *ngFor="let choice of field.choices">
                            <ion-label>{{ choice.text }}</ion-label>
                            <ion-radio value="{{ choice.value }}"></ion-radio>
                        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
```